# Features detection with ARToolKit?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, artoolkit, freak

I'm using ARToolKit in an android app and i would like to do a features detection (probably with FREAK because now ARToolKit uses it) in an image. My goal is just to have the number of key points in the image. But I don't find the tools to do just this "simple" task.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should look at OpenCV and their implementation of FREAK.  There are JAVA wrappers for OpenCV which work on android.

You'll find lot's of tutorials and info at their website and forum.

Here is a similar answer with C++ code. Shouldn't be hard to convert it to Java using OpenCV's own wrappers.

[OpenCV FREAK: Fast Retina KeyPoint descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491022/opencv-freak-fast-retina-keypoint-descriptor)

Regards,

Daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel
I knew I could do that with openCV but i wanted to avoid adding it just for that because ARToolkit already uses FREAK. But I think I will not have the choice